# What kind of uniform is this, with a closed collar on a WWI British General?

Tags: military, identification, world-war-one, united-kingdom, uniform

The British Army's Service Dress uniform ["has been referred to as No. 2 Dress, with the tunic being swapped out for a jacket with an open collar for wear with collared shirt and tie."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_dress_uniform#British_Army) [King George V](https://redd.it/wlqkaj) and [John French](https://redd.it/85w0zb) sported red gorget patches on their open collars.

[image]

[image]

But in the [2015 Australian TV miniseries *Gallipoli*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallipoli_(miniseries)), [John Bach (actor for Sir Ian Hamilton) wore a closed collar without gorget patches](https://www.filmweb.pl/person/John+Bach-66333/photos)!

##### Why did Bach wear this variant? What's this uniform variant called? Was this uniform variant historically accurate?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It has been said that if you see two British generals with identical uniforms then one of them is a spy.

Comment: Looks like a 1902 field service tunic.  Senior officer version, much nicer fabric that that worn by Joe Private.  No red gorget patches?  If you are the senior officer present, who gets to tell you you're out of uniform?

Comment: @DrMcCleod I never heard this before! Why is that? Or are you joking?